# Combining Two CD-ROMs

Tags: burning, compact-disc, combine

Is there any way to combine two CDs? I have two game discs that I would like to put on one CD for easier distribution. These games are very very old and are only about 250 megs for their entire contents.

Since they depend on their paths to run correctly, is there a way to write them to a disc in a certain way that makes windows think they're two separate discs?

Comment: do any of the paths overlap?

Comment: Yes they do. Thus the reason for my concern. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the games have copy protection, you may be out of luck (unless you also have a No-CD or similar... but thats up to you, and I wouldn't recommend it).

If the games just come on cd, simply create a new folder somewhere and then two sub folders, `Disk 1` and `Disk 2`, copy everything from the cd to the relevant folder and use your favourite burning tool such as [CDBurnerXP](http://www.cdburnerxp.se) or [ImgBurn](http://www.imgburn.com/) (Both available on [Ninite](http://www.ninite.com)).

Now, when you put the disk in, simply go to the relevant folder and install. If the game does have copy protection, you may have luck with Jared's answer (I would use [Clone Drive](http://www.slysoft.com/en/virtual-clonedrive.html) over Daemon Tools), simply because that trys to emulate the copy protection - obviously though you have to install that on each machine you want to use, but you can always keep the setup file on the root of the disk.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any way to burn a CD so that Windows thinks it's more than one disc.

It's possible to use a program like [ImgBurn](http://www.imgburn.com/) to create `.iso` files of the discs and then burn them onto a single CD/DVD.

Then, you can mount the `.iso` file with a CD/DVD emulator like SlySoft's [Virtual CloneDrive](http://www.slysoft.com/en/virtual-clonedrive.html) or [DaemonTools](http://www.daemon-tools.cc/). You could even mount the iso files right off your burned disc.